# Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png when using an mp3 file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle 1.5.0 with Android Studio. Project syncs with Gradle without any issues, but when I run the app, I get the follow error message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App:mergeDebugResources'.
/Users/Zee/Repos/App/res/drawable/notification.mp3: Error: The filename must end with .xml or .png
```

Using an mp3 file, so not sure what to do at this point. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put mp3 file in drawable. Drawable folder is for images. Put your mp3 file or any other format in raw folder.

Raw folder can be found in `res/raw`
If it doesn't exist then just create a `raw` folder in `res` folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible cause**

Another scenario causing the error might be, that you must have mistakenly pasted your whole `drawable-xxxhdpi/xxhdpi/xhdpi/hdpi/mdpi` folder in your `drawable` folder which may have resulted in **cascading of drawable folder** and thus giving this error.

**Solution**

Just go to that folder & **delete the unwanted/extra folders**.Then the issue will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I

I had .zip file containing grandle files, in `res/drawable" folder. Then I deleted it from the "drawable"
directory. It worked for me...

Answer (score -2):

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App:mergeDebugResources'.
/Users/Zee/Repos/App/res/drawable/notification.mp3: Error: The filename must end with .xml or .png
```

this error occurrs when we attempt to delete all files except `.xml` and `.png` from all folders in our package.

e.g. If the assets folder has the files debug.exe and java.exe, and we want to delete them