# The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and I am using some Paint.Net images (.pdn) and also some icons in .pptx format.
I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533861/android-using-svg-in-res-leads-to-error-the-file-name-must-end-with-xml-or) .

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2' in gradle.properties
```

But on applying it I get the below error :

```
Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a><br><a href="https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy">Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle</a>
```

I added below proxy configuration inside the gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.host.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=portnum
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userId
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=passWord
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.host.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=portNum
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userId
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=passwoRd
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

But then I get this error:

```
Error:Cause: peer not authenticated
```

and then I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734738/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated), which says the Gradle version has to be correct in the build.gradle.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
```

Now I am in a deadLock!
Does Android not support .pdn or .pptx in drawable?

Comment: see: [Android: Using SVG in res leads to error: “The file name must end with .xml or .png”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984023/error-the-file-name-must-end-with-xml-or-png-when-using-an-mp3-file)

Answer (score 0):

> Does Android Studio 1.5.1 cant support .pdn or .pptx in drawable?

Android Studio does not support `.pdn` or `.pptx` as drawable resources.

Comment: I just want to ask would they not be supported if placed in raw folder??

Comment: @VivekMishra: They would be fine in `res/raw/`. I said that they are not supported as drawable resources.

Comment: I am just asking out of curiosity if they will be supported in raw or not. I am not asking about drawables as I know they will not work in drawables

Comment: @VivekMishra: In general, anything can go in `res/raw/`, as Android does not attempt to infer any particular sort of content is in there. You're still subject to limitations like filenames (must be a valid Java field name). But I am not aware of anything you can't put in `res/raw/`.

Comment: Android Studio is wrong though - this is reproducible with other IDEs or editors using the standard framework and SDK with Gradle. It's an Android restriction

Answer (score 0):

Android accepts only .png, .jpg, .gif and .xml files as drawable resources. For more information look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)