# AndroidStudio 2.1 + Gradle 2.13 - altering the new rules that restricts drawable artifacts to only .png and .xml files

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

What's the sociably acceptable tweak to the gradle 2.13 rule set, to permit something other than a **.png** or **.xml** file as a drawable eg.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/... /app/src/main/res/drawable/background.svg: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
```

**FYI**: renaming the .svg to a .xml doesn't work with the rule-set, as .svg files don't have a DOCTYPE, which there's also a gradle requirement for, and so on.

Comment: A method that isn't likely be deprecated / disappear in the next gradle tweak, as now uncool.

Comment: see: [Android: Using SVG in res leads to error: “The file name must end with .xml or .png”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984023/error-the-file-name-must-end-with-xml-or-png-when-using-an-mp3-file)

Comment: the linked post is only for mp3 file. Here is asking for svg files

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

to svg file